# How to access multiple options for a command line flag in bash

Tags: bash, input, command-line, arguments, getopts

I want to access multiple command line inputs for flags, but I can't get it to work. The input order is out of my control, with the format being (# are numbers, not comments)

```
./program.sh -a -b # #
./program.sh -b # # -a
./program.sh -b # #
```

- `-a` has no options, it is just a toggle on/off
- `-b` is always followed by two numbers.

I have tried using `getopts`, and that works for `-a` and the first number of `-b`, but i cannot access the second number. As sometimes `-a` comes after `-b`, treating the 'remainder' of the input as a string doesn't work as intended.
I tried using a loop that when it found `-b`, looked at the next two values to set, shown below:

```
for i in "$@"; do 
    case "$i" in
        -a)
            upperCase=true;
            ;;
        -b)
            first=$(($i+1));
            second=$(($i+2));
            ;;
        *)
            ;;

    esac
done
```

output should be the letters from # to # in both directions printed, but I have got that working, my only issue is actually receiving the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this loop would work, instead:

```
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
do
    case "$1" in
        -a)
            upperCase=true;
            ;;
        -b)
            first=$2;  # Take the next two arguments
            second=$3; 
            shift 2    # And shift twice to account for them
            ;;
        *)
            ;;

    esac
    shift  # Shift each argument out after processing them
done
```

`$(($i+1))` is just adding one to the variable `i`, instead of taking the next positional parameter as you wanted.

Comment: I understand the logic here, but bash says it doesn't work with this error

./create_pattern.sh: line 43: [: -gt: unary operator expected

./create_pattern.sh: line 47: [: -lt: unary operator expected

./create_pattern.sh: line 51: [: -gt: unary operator expected

./create_pattern.sh: line 55: [: -lt: unary operator expected

Comment: @Frogglet what's the actual code producing the error?

Comment: Oh, sorry i thought i had the code in there. Later on I check to make sure the number is within the range 1-26. The error comes from various lines similar to 
if [ $first -gt 26 ], and I then set the value to 26 (in this case). I have also noticed that echo statements, (echo $first) produce nothing.

Comment: Nevermind, I discovered the issue was due to me not using dos2unix when before running my code, and hence ubuntu was using a back up version of the dos2unix-ed code.

Comment: @Frogglet in addition to that, when using `[ ... ]` instead of `[[ ... ]]`, **quote your variables**.